# Routing solid copper Cat5e directly to switch

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, cat5e

I'm upgrading a house from wifi to a wired connection.
The house has a basement, 1st floor, 2nd floor, 3rd floor.
The internet connection is 300mbps.

I've read a lot about patch bays and wiring through dry wall - unfortunately these aren't options.

Instead I will be drilling a hole through the floors and wiring along the surface of the floor.

Can I connect my ISPs modem directly to a wired router (eg. ubiquity edgerouter) and from this router run solid copper Cat5e to 3 other endpoints? The location is from the basement, to the 1st floor, 2nd floor and then a few metres horizontally and vertically to the 3rd floor.
Will any of this setup degrade the internet connection noticeably? The aim is to make sure the TVs and ps4 have the best internet access.

```
(ISP)--(basement edge router)--|-- (1st floor - directly into apple tv)
                               |-- (2nd floor - Access point)--|--(Wire to apple tv)
                               |-- (3rd floor - switch)--|-- (wire to PS4)
                                                         |-- (Access point)
```

Comment: Your (upside-down) diagram shows a single connection to all 3 floors and your  description doesn't provide any clarification.  You could cascade the signal using switches on the first two floors.  But for the *"best internet access"* you need individual cable runs from the router to each floor (assuming your *"router"* has an integrated switch, i.e. 3 downstream ports).

Comment: @sawdust thank you for your comment and keen eyesight

Answer (score 2):

Solid CAT5e works the same way as Stranded CAT5e.  If you are not going to use professional punched down terminations, then do not use solid CAT5e. Stick to stranded because RJ45 terminations are much easier to make with stranded wire.  I have put Ethernet in my own home this way.

Otherwise, what you are trying to do will work.

Comment: Solid UTP cable is preferred over stranded for in-wall and permanent installations.  There is less signal loss when using solid UTP cable.  See https://www.txmstore.com/blog/solid-vs-stranded-for-cat5e-and-cat6-cables/  and https://www.black-box.de/en-de/page/25233/Resources/Technical-Resources/Black-Box-Explains/Copper-Cable/solid-vs-stranded-patch-cable

Comment: *"...must be professionally installed"* !!??  You exaggerate.  There is no licensing or certification required, just skill in using a punch-down tool.  I installed solid UTP to ten wall-plates that have no issues over 12 years of use, and I'm not a *"professional installer"*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can absolutely do this.  Cat 5e has a max length per segment of 100 meters, which I am fairly sure you wont exceed in a house.

I do want to point out that you have other options.

You dont have to drill holes and run cable throughout the house.  You can go wireless.  802.11ac WiFi is faster than your internet speed, so there will be no slowdown there.

Alternatively, you can use powerline ethernet adapters.  These allow you to network your devices through the house's electric wiring.  It is also faster than your internet speed, easy to set up, and reliable.  Ive been using powerline networking at home for years and find it to be the best and most convenient option.

Comment: Thanks @Keltari. The house is very weird. Wifi is only workable on the floor the AP is on. and trying powerlines gave me a terrible connection.

Comment: Reposition the AP?

Comment: @spikey_richie moving it impacts the performance in current location. want to improve overall network performance. not just one specific area.

Answer (score 0):

Think about future-proofing, unless you're planning on only being there a couple of years… in which case **plan on future-proofing!**

I moved into my 5-storey building for a few months… 30 years ago.

When I wired it, Cat5e was the best you could get. Next time there's a significant upshift in ethernet speed - which already exists, just not at consumer-level - I'll have to re-wire it.

If you're going solid cable, why not plan for Cat6… or 7?
The wiring task is such that you don't want to have to do it twice inside 10 years, or even 30.
It doesn't matter how much of a task it is this time; if you have to do it again, it will feel worse.

Your routes/cable costs are not the important factor, your termination, internal hub/switches are replaceable as standards improve, so look to the most comprehensive structure in the first place. Leave enough slack behind termination plates that you can re-configure in future without ending up tight.

Radiating cabling from a single switch nearest the incoming ISP data point is the most cable-efficient, even if some of the runs are long. Keeping the runs under maximum shouldn't be too hard, you can run 100m before needing a repeater. While you're making any one run, you could always do two at the same time, in case you need more or one breaks.

Don't jump to wireless to get past an awkward wall - jump outside the house & wire it externally -  & don't bother with powerline - it will fail at every fuse/breaker it has to pass.

Answer (score 0):

All your devices will share the internet connection, so there will be contention. If you for example use BitTorrent without throttling, it will take up a lot of bandwidth and may make your Netflix start-stoppy.
IP traffic can be prioritised using QoS settings, if your endpoints and the router support it. This is used, for example, to prioritise VoIP to avoid excessive jitter and lag.